# Website Dev: Rendering's Views on Server-side vs Client-side?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, mustache, handlebars.js

I need to ask you guys/gals out there about a concept of website development that I'm not finding a whole lot of documentation about. Maybe I'm using the wrong vocabulary? It's basicly rendering the views (in a MVC type sites) on the client side vs server side.

Here's what I know so far. Commonly in a Model, Controller, View type website, the view is what the HTML/CSS/Javascript design gets programmed to. Now the idea is that the server processes all the HTML/CSS/Javascript, and what gets sent to the client browser, is the finished view. I believe this applies to C#, MS.net, Java, PHP, as well as Rails.

Now, the way client-side works is, the server stops at trying to render views for HTML/CSS/Javascript, and instead only renders views for raw XML data. In addition, a Javascript like program (handlebars.js and mustache.js, eg) is downloaded once, cached, and the XML data is feed through the javascript program which in turn dynamically creates the HTML/CSS/Javascript view. The idea behind this is that only XML data, the initial JS program, and media are the only things needed from the server. Instead of refreshing the page each time, only XML or JSON data is needed.

Now, I can see an advantage for a small business that wishes to advertise, blogs, resellers, etc. 1. Minimize the amount of raw data that comes out of the company server, and 2. Send media and precompiled code to a cloud serving site like amazon.com.

But what if all information needs to be served from the company's servers? It seems to me that a number of arguments towards choosing client-side have already been addressed in Rails 3+

How can I find out more information about this so I can make a more knowledgeable decision as to choose client vs server?

All comments are welcome! Thanks (^_^)

Comment: Full Client-Side development is great... if you're sure your users have modern browsers. Much harder to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Servers only touch PHP, Java, ASP.NET(C# and VB.NET), etc. JavaScript is a Client Side Code. the MVC Model is more for the Server side code on how you break it up. It tries to keep the logic away from the design. a good example of how this works would be [Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-1-introduction-to-magento).

Also, client-side code is [vulnerable to hackers](http://blog.sabretoothglobal.com/client-side-hacking-demystified/)

http://php-html.net/tutorials/model-view-controller-in-php/

Comment: It has been quite a while, and I was hoping to see some additional comments. However, I tend to believe you are correct as that was beliefs on this as well (and still is). But, I was hoping that someone would prove us wrong and add some additional insight that I might not have thought of before. Thanks.